# Remove everything after the first / including the first / for each line

Tags: perl, sed

I have a file with lots of host names. Some have a url part after the host that I'd like to remove. In other words:

```
google.com
facebook.com
acme.com/news/frontpage
bbc.co.uk
abc.com/home/index
```

Should become

```
google.com
facebook.com
acme.com
bbc.co.uk
abc.com
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
sed 's|/.*||' file
```

Results:

```
google.com
facebook.com
acme.com
bbc.co.uk
abc.com
```

You may want to read more about using the [slash as a delimiter](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2). HTH.

Comment: thanks that worked - only one minor thing - it added ^M to end of each line when I redirect the output to a file. I'm on linux.

Comment: You can run `dos2unix file` to remove DOS/Windows newline-ending characters. Then run the `sed` command. Alternatively, use `awk`. Try: `awk -F/ '{ print $1 }' RS="\r\n" file`

Comment: Many thanks. Out of interest, why does it add the ^M? The original file doesn't have it.

Comment: @smithy: If I were you, I'd check again. I'm almost certain the original file contains the `^M`. But I've been wrong before. Try `cat -A file`

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
cut -d '/' -f1 file.txt
```

or

```
awk -F/ '{print $1}' file.txt
```

or

```
perl -F/ -lane 'print $F[0]' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F/ '{print $1}' your_file
```

or

all the other solutions cannot change the file inplace.but in case of steve you need to add a -i flag for that sed solution.But still it will not work on solaris.
below perl solutiopn works on all the platform and replaces the file inplace

```
perl -pi -e 's/\/.*//g' your_file
```